# Custom Symfony2 Validator Constraint Messages

Tags: validation, symfony

I want to use custom error messages for validation constraints on dozens of fields in my project.

I do not want to set the message on every one of these, because that would be a blatant violation of DRY. Repeating the same string in every declaration like: `@NotNull(message="custom msg")` would mean that if I decide to change the message in the future I'd have to hunt them all down replace them, but even worse I might use the wrong string on some of them and be inconsistent.

How do you deal with this?

Is the best option really to extend every symfony stock constraint and set my default there, and use my own custom annotation class?

*Please note that using the translator is not an option for me, so I am looking for a solution that does not include the symfony translation component.*

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with English as the app's language, and you've configured `translator: { fallback: en }`, you can override these constraint messages universally. Start by creating this file: `app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml`

And use the following translation format:

```
This value should not be blank.: Your custom message here
Whatever the standard message is.: Another custom message
```

This also works for any other language setting, assuming you've made a `validators.lang.yml` for it!

You can also place this file in your bundle directory under `Resources/translations`, and a few other places.

You can [read more about this here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages)!

Comment: I could do that but I want to avoid using the translator (I have my own translation for this project). I do not have the translator enabled. I am basically looking for a solution without needing to do a 1-1 translation in a YAML file.

Comment: @ChrisTickner Sorry, that's your "best option." It's also the recommended option by the Symfony docs, as I've referenced. Otherwise you do have to extend each stock constraint, but that's not very DRY.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This will likely be the only option aside from extending them. I changed my original question after this post to reflect my situation that I should have added originally. Thanks again!